# XElement.Remove() not fully removing element with specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a simple command that looks through an XML file and deletes any elements with an attribute matching that of a provided string. However, a problem occurs when deleting the element. Here is my code:

```
public async Task RemoveX(string name)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var node = doc.Element("Reactions")
        .Elements("ReactionRole")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == name);

    node.Remove();
    using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        doc.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file before normally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Reactions>
  <ReactionRole name="test">
    <MessageID>699904390907035668</MessageID>
    <RoleID>663891376748101643</RoleID>
  </ReactionRole>
  <ReactionRole name="help">
    <MessageID>4518765213548745345</MessageID>
    <RoleID>456165487369178913</RoleID>
  </ReactionRole>
</Reactions>
```

And here is the same file after I try to remove the element with attribute "test"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Reactions>
  <ReactionRole name="help">
    <MessageID>4518765213548745345</MessageID>
    <RoleID>456165487369178913</RoleID>
  </ReactionRole>
</Reactions>le name="help">
    <MessageID>4518765213548745345</MessageID>
    <RoleID>456165487369178913</RoleID>
  </ReactionRole>
</Reactions>
```

I've looked around and don't see anything that is going wrong. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File.OpenWrite` does not overwrite the file, just change it to `File.Create` which will overwrite the file if it exists.

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, a simpler solution would be to use the overload of [`XDocument.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Save_System_String_) that accepts a file name - `doc.Save(path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`File.OpenWrite`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,a30071aa09897b66) open a file with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` that specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise, a new file should be created, and do not overwrite it if it exists. so for save our's document we must overwrite existsing file and open a `FileStream` with `FileMode.Create`, that specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Just replace

```
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
   doc.Save(fs);
}
```

with

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
   doc.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation...